# не работает отдельный код вне потока

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

имеется код. выполняется в отдельном потоке

```
def systeminit():
    code code code....

checker = Thread(target=systeminit())
checker.setDaemon(True)
checker.start()
```

так же имеется ивен хэндлер

```
@serverbot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def iddetector(message):
        serverbot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ID detected: ' + str(message.chat.id))
    idlogger(message)
```

если отключить поток на первой функции - тогда message.handler работает
но функция мониторинга не работает (срабатывает один раз)

если обратно включить поток - мониторинг работает, но вот хэндлер событий не работает, и бот не отвечает на запросы. 
как это обойти? мне нужно, что бы в одном потоке работал мониторинг, и одновременно хэндрел работал
спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

```
checker = Thread(target=systeminit())
```

заменить на

```
checker = Thread(target=systeminit)
```